# SignalR / Ajax method calling

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wpf, signalr

I'm currently migrating an existing solution to SignalR (for real time update purpose). The legacy server side was an ASP.NET MVC and is now a WPF application Self hosting SignalR. I want to make my solution backwards compatible as much as possible for the client but all the existing client-side code use Ajax 'post/get' syntax to call server methods like this :

```
 $.ajax({
          url: 'api/Controller/Action',
          type: "POST",
          success: function (result) { ...   },
  });
```

Is it possible in any way to intercept these method calls from the SignalR point of view without adding hub connection and/or changing client side code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some workaround i've found a solution so i post it here if looking for a solution to the same kind of problem.

It's possible to use both [SignalR SelfHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host) and [WebApi SelfHost](https://www.asp.net/web-api)

in Startup.Cs class in my wpf app i simply put extra HttpConfiguration aside the SignalR one.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        // SignalR configuration etc...

    }
```

Then i created a custom class that derivate from ApiController and use it like a standard MVC controller.